# How to send post request with python script from server to database using SIM808?

Tags: python, database, http-post

I'm receiving an error when my code python code runs the command AT+HTTPREAD. Also, can't get the command to exit, so it's creating an error when I try to run again, so i have to restart the module. Debugging allows me to send the data at some point, but program won't run on it's own.

I have tried to run with the AT+HTTPREAD command commented out. I have also tried to close the module using the command AT+SAPBR, but without success. I have received  different result when i run at each command after test run failure.

```
import serial
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=19200, timeout=3)

def execute(cmd):
    global port
    msg = (cmd + '\r').encode()
    port.write(msg)
    result = port.read(100).decode()
    return result

def close_all():
    cmd = "AT+SAPBR=0,1"
    result = execute(cmd)
    print(result)
    port.close()
    exit(1)

cmd = "AT"
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)
if "ERROR" in result:
    exit(1)

cmd = "AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"\",\"\""
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)
if "ERROR" in result:
    close_all()

cmd = "AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"\",\"""
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)
if "ERROR" in result:
    close_all()

cmd = "AT+SAPBR=1,1"
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)
if "ERROR" in result:
    close_all()

cmd = "AT+SAPBR=2,1"
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)
if "ERROR" in result:
    close_all()


cmd = "AT+HTTPINIT"
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)
if "ERROR" in result:
    close_all()


cmd = "AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1"
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)
if "ERROR" in result:
    close_all()

cmd = "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http:""
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)
if "ERROR" in result:
    close_all()

cmd = "AT+HTTPACTION=1"
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)
if "ERROR" in result:
    close_all()


cmd = "AT+HTTPREAD=0,100"
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)
if "ERROR" in result:
    close_all()

cmd = "AT+HTTPTERM"
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)


close_all()
```

I'm expecting this to test my server ability to read and write the data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

My error was in the command line. I left out the "P" of 'HTTREAD'. Correct command is 'AT+HTTPREAD= 0,100'.

```
cmd = "AT+HTTPREAD=0,100"
result = execute(cmd)
print(result)
if "ERROR" in result:
    close_all()
```